# administer drug dose at certain time step in octave

Tags: octave

I am doing a simple task on ocatve. 
I have to administer drug dose at day 1,7,21 and 28..

i wrote a function like that:

```
   function xdot = f (x,t)

   a=[1;7;21;28]
   drug=0; ### initially drug is zero

   if (t==a)
   drug=drug+57.947;

  else
  drug=drug+0;
  endif

  xdot=(-0.4077)*(x)+ drug; passing the value of drug to differential equation

  endfunction
```

In the main file i called this function in lsode:

```
  t=linspace(0,30,30);
  x0=0;
  y=lsode(@ex,x0,t); ### ex is the file name where function is written
  plot(t,y,'o')
```

This program doesn't work.. it displays all the time zero value for drug. Can anybody help me that how to administer dug dose with certain time step by manipulating linspace function.

Comment: Please check the expression `t==a` on the interpreter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a simple clearance model, and at each time in `a`, you want the dose to be delivered *instantaneously*.  That is, at each time in `a`, the amount of drug in the subject increases by 57.947.

If that is the model that you have in mind, implementing it in the formula for `xdot` will not work well.  You would actually need to implement it as a ["delta function"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function), and `lsode` won't work with that.

Instead, I recommend solving the problem in stages, corresponding to the time intervals [0, 1], [1, 7], [7, 21], and [21, 28].  During one stage, the differental equation is simply `xdot = -0.4077*x`.  In the first stage, the initial condition is 0.  In the next stage, the initial condition is the final value of the previous stage plus the dosage amount 57.947.

Here's a script:

```
dose = 57.947;
a = [1 7 21 28 30];

x0 = 0.0;
t0 = 0;
t = [];
y = [];
for t1 = a
    tinterval = linspace(t0, t1, 2*(t1 - t0) + 1);
    yinterval = lsode(@(x, t) -0.4077*x, x0, tinterval);
    t = [t tinterval];
    y = [y yinterval'];
    t0 = t1;
    x0 = yinterval(end) + dose;
end

plot(t, y, "linewidth", 2);
```

The script creates this plot:

[image: drug dose plot]

---

Note that the differential equation `xdot = -k*x` has the solution `x0*exp(-k*(t-t0))`, so the call to `lsode` could be replaced with

```
    yinterval = x0*exp(-0.4077*(tinterval - t0));
```

If you do this, also remove the transpose from `yinterval` two lines below:

```
    y = [y yinterval];
```

---

If you want to keep the implementation of the administration of the drug dose within the formula for `xdot`, you'll need to distribute it over a small time interval.  It could be implemented as a short rectangular pulse of width `w` and height 57.974/`w`.  You'll also need to ensure that `lsode` takes sufficiently small internal time steps (less than `w`) so that it "sees" the drug dose.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want replace `t==a` by `ismember (t, a)`. Also, you should erase the `else` clause as it has no effect on the answer.

---

**UPDATE**

Consider rewriting your function as:

```
function xdot = f (x,t)
  xdot = -0.4077*x + 57.947*ismember (t, [1 7 21 28])
endfunction
```

Comment: Thanks Julio, i did the same as you suggested but still result is same. I assume that the problem lies with my t function. Because the values of t are in negative and much different when i displayed it on function file as compared to the values displayed in main file. may be its lsode function, which is changing the values of t. in this case what should be done? i am sorry if question seems to be stupid because my background is in biology. kindly help me to understand this.

Comment: @shm, I updated the answer. Please be sure to read the help pages for `lsode`, type `help lsode` on the interpreter.